# Deeplinking to an android app

Tags: android, deep-linking

Can we implement deeplinking for a mobile app without having a website or do we have to have a predefined specific website to implemment it?

Comment: use adb  in terminal.                                                                                            $ adb shell am start
        -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
        -d <URI> <PACKAGE>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep linking can work without having a specific website. All you need for it to work is add the `<intent-filter> ... </intent-filter>` tag to your preferred activity via the AndroidManifest.

Then create a unique URI pattern intended to match any HTTP URI such as `http://your-app-domain/content` or a custom scheme such as `your-app://content`. Add this scheme to the `<data ... />`  tag.

Here's what your activity should look like when you're done.

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.DeepLinkingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_deeplink">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="your-app-domain"
                    android:pathPrefix="/content"
                    android:scheme="http" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Regardless of the URI scheme you choose, you should be able to begin your activity when an intent with the scheme is triggered.

If you are familiar with adb commands, enter this command

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://your-app-domain/content" com.your-app-package
```

Further reading https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app